# Where does the SELECT clause start/end

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, grammar

Perhaps this is a pedantic distinction, but if we take the SQL grammar, in the following case from [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax):

```
query_statement:
    query_expr

query_expr:
    [ WITH [ RECURSIVE ] { non_recursive_cte | recursive_cte }[, ...] ]
    { select | ( query_expr ) | set_operation }
    [ ORDER BY expression [{ ASC | DESC }] [, ...] ]
    [ LIMIT count [ OFFSET skip_rows ] ]

select:
    SELECT
        [ { ALL | DISTINCT } ]
        [ AS { STRUCT | VALUE } ]
        select_list
    [ FROM from_clause[, ...] ]
    [ WHERE bool_expression ]
    [ GROUP BY { expression [, ...] | ROLLUP ( expression [, ...] ) } ]
    [ HAVING bool_expression ]
    [ QUALIFY bool_expression ]
    [ WINDOW window_clause ]
```

It is easy to see, for example, that the `WHERE` clause would be the section:

```
[ WHERE bool_expression ]
```

However, what is considere the "select clause". Is it the wrapper that contains everything? Or is it just the part that goes from `SELECT` up until the `FROM` section? Is there a way to distinguish the two?

For a specific example, how would the following be defined:

```
SELECT 1
FROM x
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2
```

With the three components labeled with:

- `[` (full)
- `{` (SELECT until end or set/op)
- `<` (SELECT until FROM):

```
[
  {<SELECT 1> FROM x} 
  UNION ALL
  {<SELECT 2>}
]
```

Comment: Distinguish in what way? [Another part](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select_list) of the docs you linked to describe the `SELECT Statement` fairly clearly

Comment: @HoneyBadger thanks. So in that link it calls the part from `SELECT` until FROM as the `Select Statement`. And then I suppose the entire thing is just the `Select` ? It seems bit confusing to me (select vs. selectClause vs. selectStatement vs. selectWithSetOperator).

Comment: it is not confusind You ca do a CTE `WITH a AS () SELECT * FROM a` or a `SELCT * FROM b` the SELECT follows the same rules, and the CTE enxtends the SELRCT

Comment: @nbk -- of course, this isn't a question about what can be done, but rather how to name the different parts.

Comment: the order of the statements you see in your is the prder in which all clauses have to appear. to the dot else you get an error

Comment: @David542 maybe it would help if you could explain why you need to know. Or is it just general curiosity? And are you just interested in BigQuery or SQL in general (which would make this pretty much unanswerable)?

Comment: `select_list` is defined farther down the page under the heading of "SELECT statement" which is perhaps a bit misleading.

Comment: @HoneyBadger for parsing definitions/rules. Just BigQuery is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The SELECT **statement** is the whole statement from the word SELECT until the end.

The SELECT **clause** is from the word SELECT until the word FROM

Comment: Unless there is an `INTO` between the `SELECT` and the `FROM`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid what if there is a set operation, such as `SELECT 1 FROM x UNION ALL SELECT 2`. How would these three be defined `<{[SELECT 1] FROM x} UNION ALL {[SELECT 2]}>`

Comment: Yep I agree it's much more complicated than "the stuff between select and from"